# MouseListener starts giving errors mid-runtime

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I am currently in progress of making a game involving a button made via JPanel. However, at some point during the program's runtime, the JPanel used to make the button begins to give constant errors whenever a mouse event is registered in the following form:

```
at java.awt.AWTEventMultiCaster.mouse[eventName](UnknownSource)
```

It goes so fast that I can't see the initial error, and the error only begins at some point during mid-runtime. Can anybody help me out here? The following is the code for my JPanel:

```
JPanel trackPanel = new JPanel() {
        int state = 0;
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponents(g);

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (dragMe == null) {
                        state = 1;
                    }
                }
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (dragMe == null) state = 0;
                    else state = 1;
                }
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (dragMe == null && !e.isMetaDown())
                    {
                        dragMe = new DragFrameThread(vTrack);
                        dragMe.start();
                    }
                    state = 2;
                }
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (state == 2 && e.isMetaDown()) System.exit(0);
                    if (dragMe != null) {
                        dragMe.interrupt();
                        dragMe = null;
                        state = 1;
                    }
                }
            });

            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 255));
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 223));
            g.drawRect(1, 1, getWidth()-3, getHeight()-3);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 191));
            g.drawRect(2, 2, getWidth()-5, getHeight()-5);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 159));
            g.fillRect(3, 3, getWidth()-6, getHeight()-6);

            g.drawImage(BootAssets.VTScaledLogo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

            if (state == 1) g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 127));
            if (state == 2) g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 127));
            if (state != 0) g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            repaint();
        }
    };
```

Thanks a bunch!
~Para

Comment: I may be not following the code here, but it appears that the paintComponet is registering a new listener every time it is called. Shouldn't the listener be added once to the trackPanel and not on every paint call?

Comment: That looks like the right answer @KevinO

Comment: @KevinO Well, the problem there is that I can't seem to add the listener in any location other than the paintComponent.

Comment: @UnityParadox, I am going to presume the rationale for being unable to move the listener is because the state variable is defined inside the JPanel. See my answer for a suggestion, but the approach in the example code is not good OO-design. I would consider subclassing JPanel instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the `paintComponent` method is called when the widget is painted. Adding a mouse listener on every paint call is wrong.

Move the addMouseListener out of the paintComponent method and add it separately to the trackPanel. You will need to refactor the code since it currently has the state set and updated in the way the JPanel is defined.

```
       private final AtomicInteger state = new AtomicInteger(0);
       JPanel trackPanel = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 255));
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 223));
            g.drawRect(1, 1, getWidth()-3, getHeight()-3);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 191));
            g.drawRect(2, 2, getWidth()-5, getHeight()-5);
            g.setColor(new Color(0, 127, 127, 159));
            g.fillRect(3, 3, getWidth()-6, getHeight()-6);

            g.drawImage(BootAssets.VTScaledLogo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

            if (state.get() == 1) g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 127));
            if (state.get() == 2) g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 127));
            if (state.get() != 0) g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());                
        }
    };

    trackPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (dragMe == null) {
                state.set(1);
            }
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            if (dragMe == null) state.set(0);
            else state.set(1);
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (dragMe == null && !e.isMetaDown())
            {
                dragMe = new DragFrameThread(vTrack);
                dragMe.start();
            }
            state.set(2);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (state.get() == 2 && e.isMetaDown()) System.exit(0);
            if (dragMe != null) {
                dragMe.interrupt();
                dragMe = null;
                state.set(1);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, after your initial reply, I found a different solution in making a private boolean within the JPanel's code and testing if it's true, and if it's not, adding the listener and setting it to true. Would the solution you provided be more efficient?

Comment: @UnityParadox, The solution in the answer is marginally more efficient since you would not check to see if the listener needed to be added each time. It is also cleaner code to not clutter a paint callback with adding a listener. It is a confusing place to add a listener. Readability and maintainability are also important considerations, not just making the code work. What happens when you need to refactor something? The paint method should deal only with painting. Make the method do the single thing it is designed to do. Add the mouse listener to the panel outside the paint callback.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll check this later, as I'm not able to at the moment.